# How to extract images from Images in Form?

Tags: image, vb6, jpeg, immediate-window

I have an old VB6 project which has a form containing a number of `Image` objects.  That was the way the author had stored images to use on buttons etc. on other forms.

How can I extract the images from these objects to something like a `JPG` or `BMP`?

I was hoping for something to put into the `Immediate` window.  I don't mind doing it one by one.

Comment: It's not immediately clear to me what you were asking.  I see you found the answer yourself, but it might be helpful for future visitors to understand your question better.  Were you looking to extract the images from the source code?  Or from a compiled DLL?  Or at run-time?

Comment: I just wanted to do it at design time, just to extract the images.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SavePicture MyImage.Picture, "mypic.bmp"
```